# What's the difference between /token and /authorize in Microsoft Graph?

Tags: oauth-2.0, microsoft-graph-api, openid

I send my users to `/authorize` and I get back an access token. Am I done? Can I now send emails and create calendar events on behalf of the users? Or to I now have to send them to `/token`?

Why does `/token` even exist if I can get just the token from `/authorize`?

Comment: This is standard OAuth2 architecture.  You get an authorization code from the Authorization server and use that to get a token from token server.

Comment: What's the point if I already get a code from /authorize?

Comment: @AskYous: https://developer.okta.com/blog/2019/10/21/illustrated-guide-to-oauth-and-oidc : Please go through this, you will realize you need need authorization code and access token to actually complete the Oauth flow

Answer (score 6):

According to your descriptions, I assume you want to know the difference between /token and /authorize in Microsoft Graph.

Following [this document](https://developer.microsoft.com/en-us/graph/docs/concepts/auth_overview#where-does-my-app-get-an-access-token), when we want to get an access token, we should exchanges HTTP request with two endpoints.

`The /authorize endpoint, where your app can send a user to authenticate with Azure AD and consent to the permissions your app needs.
The /token endpoint where your app can get an access token once user consent has been granted.`

It means that the /authorize endpoint is requesting the user to grant the appropriate permissions. Then, server will return a code.

We can use this code to get the authenticated access token.

Reference [document for OAuth2.0](https://oauth.net/2/) to learning more about authorization and authentication.

Answer (score 0):

https://developer.okta.com/blog/2019/10/21/illustrated-guide-to-oauth-and-oidc

[image: Oauth Flow]

1. You, the Resource Owner, want to allow “Terrible Pun of the Day,” the Client, to access your contacts so they can send invitations to all your friends.
2. The Client redirects your browser to the Authorization Server and includes with the request the Client ID, Redirect URI, Response Type, and one or more Scopes it needs.
3. The Authorization Server verifies who you are, and if necessary prompts for a login.
4. The Authorization Server presents you with a Consent form based on the Scopes requested by the Client. You grant (or deny) permission.
5. The Authorization Server redirects back to Client using the Redirect URI along with an Authorization Code.
6. The Client contacts the Authorization Server directly (does not use the Resource Owner’s browser) and securely sends its Client ID, Client Secret, and the Authorization Code.
7. The Authorization Server verifies the data and responds with an Access Token.
8. The Client can now use the Access Token to send requests to the Resource Server for your contacts.

So `/token` is Step 6, while `/authorize` is Step 5.